# Download all the external links such as ( pdf/images) has to be downloaded automatically

Tags: javascript, html

**I need to download externally, once user clicks on the pdf link. it has to be downloaded automatically, it should not show in the new window.**

**Below is my code**

```
function SaveToDisk_1(fileURL) {
     if (!window.ActiveXObject) {       //alert("hi");
        var save = document.createElement('a');
        save.href = fileURL;
        save.target = '_blank';
        save.download = fileURL;
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                save.dispatchEvent(evt);        alert('test')
        (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    }

 }
```

Save this page

**Please help me to resolve the issue, when i remove the "alert" i m not able to download the file in Mozila.**

Comment: <a  id="download" href=""  onclick="SaveToDisk_1('dwnld.pdf');"  >Save this page</a> here is my html code.

Comment: Did you try changing target from '_blank' to '_self' so it doesnt open in a new window.

Comment: yes Firefox is working, can anybody know how we can do it for IE ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could easily do this with a href. I will give you some examples.

**Example**

I assume your file is located in the same directory as the page. In that case you could just use an `<a href=""></a>`.

```
<a id="download" href="dwnld.pdf">Save this page</a>
```

If you need to use javascript you could do it like this. I use return false to stop a href from executing.

```
<a id="download" onclick="window.location.href='dwnld.pdf' return false;" href="">Save this page</a>
```

And if you would like to use your function. Your function would be:

```
function SaveToDisk_1(fileURL) {
     if (!window.ActiveXObject) {       //alert("hi");
        var save = document.createElement('a');
        save.href = fileURL;
        save.target = '_blank';
        save.download = fileURL;
        window.location.href = save.download;
    }

 }
```